# Changing function for inner selected elements with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible with jquery to say that if i click on a list element something happen, but if i click on an element inside that list (a span for example) nothing has to change

Example

`<li><span>hello</span></li>` if i click on the li element => alert("list"), if i click on the span element inside the li => alert("hello") butit does not have to show me the alert("list") as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, check the `event.target` node which triggered the event.

```
$('li').click(function(event){
    if (event.target. == event.currentTarget)
        // li element triggered
    else
        // inner elements triggered
});
```

[**Live STUPID DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hXV77/)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan. Not until I'll see some red circles in a demo, sir!

Comment: i didn't know could make difference but i'm using the jquery .live('click',function(){ ...})

Comment: @CarloMelisi. Why do you use `live`? it's deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `event.stopPropagation;`

http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

### *[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/b5Mun/1/)*

---

If you use the `.live()` method (and you have jQuery 1.7+) I suggest you to use the `.on` method like:

```
$('ul').on('click','li',function(){
  alert('UAAAAAAA! FOOO BARRRRR');
});

$("li").on('click','span',function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  $(this).text('See? No alert dropped! ;)');
});
```

More info at: http://api.jquery.com/on

> The .on() method attaches event handlers to the currently selected set of elements in the jQuery object. As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method provides all functionality required for attaching event handlers. For help in converting from older jQuery event methods, see .bind(), .delegate(), and .live(). To remove events bound with .on(), see .off(). To attach an event that runs only once and then removes itself, see .one()

Comment: Well nothing explode there.. but +1.

Comment: @gdoron i'm looking into browser specifics how to make explode the alert popup (...without burning the PC) ;)

Answer (score 0):

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/wB7N3/1/)**

1. Click on `Red` Border and inside - its `LIST`
2. Click on `Bluw` Border and inside - its `HELLO`

### HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span>hello</span>
    </li> 
</ul>​
```

### JS:

```
$('*').click(function() {
    if (this.tagName == "LI")
        alert("List");
    else if (this.tagName == "SPAN")
        alert("hello");
    return false;
});​
```